# Set Wordpress post status to 'Draft' from front end similar to get_delete_post_link

Tags: wordpress, post, frontend, status

I am using the below code to allow a logged in user to set delete their own posts from the front end. Is there a way to do the same thing but setting the post to 'draft' rather than deleting it completely?

```
<?php if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) { ?>
   <p><a onclick="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this?')" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ?>">Delete post</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this function `wp_update_post()`, you can test with this example:

First create a form were you want to users select if the post are going to be a draft

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="ok" name="draft">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Then create a function to save the new state put this in function.php:

```
function toDraft($pid){

$toDraft = $_POST['draft'];
   if($toDraft == 'ok'){
      echo "string";
      wp_update_post(array('ID' => $pid, 'post_status'   =>  'draft'));
  }

}
```

Then add this function below the form you create.

```
toDraft($post->ID);
```

And test. [Read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) to know more about update post status

Comment: Thanks for this. Works perfectly. How would I add an alert box to the submit and then redirect to another page?

Comment: You will need javascript to do the alert box, use jquery `submit()` function, and use `window.location` to redirect.